# NullPointer Exception handling

Tags: java

I have been going through some site where they talk about how to prevent NPE. There I saw people say use `null != object` but I don't understand why. What is the difference between doing the below in java?

```
if(null != object)
```

vs

```
if(object != null)
```

Comment: Are you sure they weren't talking about `null == object` instead? Provide your source so we see the context.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between the two in the effect.

However there is a school of thinking where it is recommended to use un-assignable (constant) values on the left hand side of a operator. Because this reduces the risk of unintended assignment (this is from the time where C compilers have been not warning about it).

```
// this is dangerous when misstyped
if (object = null) {
```

The argument that writing the null first really reduces the effect of misstyping is however pretty weak. Especially when not using "==" but "!=" or "<". So I would say, ignore those recommendations.

There are however some situations where order is helpfull to prevent NPE:

```
if ("string".equals(object))
```

In this case you dont get an NPE when "object" is null.

Comment: Note that in Java `if (object = null) {` is a compilation error because the value of `object = null` is not `boolean` as requires by the context.  The only case where that convention helps in Java is when the variable has type `boolean`.

Comment: It should also be noted that most IDE's nowadays will either give you a warning or fail to compile `if(object = null)` (I know Visual Studio refuses to). As a sidenote: passing around `null` values is a sign of a larger architecture problem so I'm not a fan of switching that string around.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - This is a Java question ... check the tags.

Comment: @StephenC: I'm aware, it was background information since I wasn't sure about the Java IDE's I've used.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - You shouldn't need to be.  Since this is Java, the 'object = null' mistake is a compilation error, *irrespective* of the IDE or the compiler.  The Java language spec says so.  Any compiler that doesn't call that a compilation error is 1) non-compliant and 2) going to generate code that will be rejected by the verifier at class load time.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between doing the below in java?

- There is no difference in terms of what the code means.
- There is no difference in terms of code safety / robustness.

In some languages, the `if (null == object)` pattern helps to avoid this mistake:

```
 if (object = null)
```

... which accidentally trashes the value of the `object` variable.

But in Java, an `if` statement requires a condition expression whose type is `boolean`, and the type of `object == null` is NOT boolean.  Hence that particular mistake / typo is guaranteed to give a compilation error.

---

Digression ...

The case where you plausibly *could* get into trouble with '==' versus '=' in classic Java is this:

```
 if (flag == true)
```

or

```
 if (flag == false)
```

However, no experienced Java programmer would write that.  Instead they would write:

```
 if (flag)
```

and

```
 if (!flag)
```

With Java 5 and onwards, autoboxing of `Boolean` can get you into trouble.  However, in that case you are doing something that is inadvisable anyway.  Consider this:

```
 Boolean TRUE = true;
 Boolean TOO_TRUE = new Boolean(true);  // generates a new instance ...

 if (TRUE == TOO_TRUE) {  // should be TRUE.equals(TRUE)
     ....
 }
```

Again, an experienced programmer would avoid using boxed types unnecessarily, and avoid testing them with `==`.  Besides, you would probably get a warning for this from an IDE or from a static anaylser like FindBugs or PMD.

Comment: It can happen for Boolean thanks to autoboxing. `Boolean b = Boolean.TRUE; boolean condition = (b = null);` or `if (b = null)` compiles (with warnings).